# MovePrevious & MoveNext iterator in C#

Tags: c#, iterator

I have implement Wizard type of screen windows forms application. In the wizard screen contains Back,Next & Finish buttons. When i click Next button i have to launch next screen in Wizard form, suppose i click Back button i have to launch previous screen in to Wizard Form. 
   I don't know how to handle screen information in Back&Next button. currently i have all screen informations in Dictionary. But i don't know how to iterate dictionary for MoveNext & MovePrevious. Dictionary enumerator contains MoveNext() method but not contain MovePrevious() method.
   How to handle Back & Next button?

Comment: Should we care to answer if you'll never accept it?  Work on that glowing 0% under your name...

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064196/controlling-user-workflow-in-winforms

Answer (score 0):

Have an integer that symbolizes your position in the wizard. Increment or decrement the integer, and load the appropriate screen.

Alternatively, use a LinkedList instead of a dictionary.