# C# adding usercontrol from different project in solution

Tags: c#, user-controls

I've created a UserControl in a separate project in the same solution I want to use it in.
My solution looks like this:

[image: Solution layout]

As you can see, I made a reference to the other project in the solution.
However, in frmWizard.cs, the user control does not appear in the toolbox.
(When I create a form in WizardPages, it does)
I tried adding a "using WizardPages.WizardPages.cs" to frmWizard.cs, but Visual Studio reported that that did not exist.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Tim

Comment: Is your class by any change marked as `Internal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to make the class public.

Comment: Very likely that is the problem. So @Tim just declare your class as `public class WizardPages` and rebuild all...

Comment: Might be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064196/controlling-user-workflow-in-winforms/2065213#2065213