# can't add user control from another solution, despite it being public

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

The following is reproducable.

I have two solutions.

One has a user control. That Solution is called testusercontrolproj

The other solution is called ProjectA

And i'm trying to get ProjectA to use a user control from that other solution, testusercontrolproj

So I created the solution with the user control - testusercontrolproj  it appears in the toolbox, fine.

I then create the solution ProjectA, which is to use the user control.  I right click the solution and choose to add an existing project, and I point it to testusercontrolproj, and I import it. And I add a reference to it. And I add a using statement for it.  And I rebuild solution and rebuild projectA. And restarting visual studio, still though -

I notice that if while within ProjectA solution, I go to the testusercontrolproj project, then I double click a form there, then click toolbox, I see the control.

However, if within ProjectA, I double click a form within ProjectA, and click the toolbox, I don't see the user control.

An answer here [C# adding usercontrol from different project in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508616/c-sharp-adding-usercontrol-from-different-project-in-solution)  suggests to make it public but The user control is public, that's the default anyway. `public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer.

No need to add the project with the user control, that doesn't help.

Right click the solution where that you want to import the user control into. So in this case, "ProjectA" then click Add, then Existing Item. Then browse to the user control in the other project, and OK.

Then you see the user control appear under the project where you want it.

[image]

And you will also find that the user control will appear in the toolbox.
(of course you may have to rebuild the solution - build..rebuild solution, but that was the case before anyway)

You can also remove the project with the user control, from your solution, and it counts for nothing, it won't bring the user control into the other project, projectA, or into the solution generally, so there's no point, and as mentioned, add the user control alone, into your project. It was the lack of that, which was the reason why I didn't get the user control in the toolbar for that project.

It does seem to make a copy though, rather than a reference.

Comment: No, don't make copies.  That will defeat the purpose of code reuse.  You have 2 Windows Form based projects in the solution - which both compile to EXEs.  Try changing the output type in the Project Properties to Class Library instead of Windows Application for testusercontrolproj, delete the copied user control and see how far you get.

Comment: I needed to add a complex user control with 2 forms and a Nuget package added in one solution to another. I did as suggested above, adding both usercontrol forms  but also had to add a reference to the dll created in the UserControl solution and add Nuget package to the main form. The usercontrol then appeared in the Toolbox, but I needed to add multiple copies programmatically. I found that  I had to refer to the UserControl as UserControl.UserControl to avoid the error message UserControl is a Namespace but is used like a type.There was still a warning message about Type ambiguity.

Comment: I also had to make the Resources in the UserControl solution Public rather than Internal to avoid a "Resource inaccessible due to Protection Level" message.

Comment: The addition of the dll reference turned out not to be required.