# control to show steps to do something in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, datagridview

i want to show steps on how to cook something in winform c# .net as steps. Something like a set of text area would be nice but:

-> list box considers the whole string of one step as one item so user needs to scroll horizontally to view the whole step.

-> datagridview is also not suitable as i want the text to word wrapped.

i also want the user to be able to edit the step.
any suggestions of custom control would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling user workflow in Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064196/controlling-user-workflow-in-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi line text box will do the job great. just take a simple text box and do the following to it, and it will turn to a text area:

```
                     TextBox listBoxNewInput  = new TextBox();
                    //Initialize label's property

                    listBoxNewInput.Multiline = true;
                    // Add vertical scroll bars to the TextBox control.
                    listBoxNewInput.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
                    // Allow the RETURN key in the TextBox control.
                    listBoxNewInput.AcceptsReturn = true;
                    // Allow the TAB key to be entered in the TextBox control.
                    listBoxNewInput.AcceptsTab = true;
                    // Set WordWrap to true to allow text to wrap to the next line.
                    listBoxNewInput.WordWrap = true;

                    listBoxNewInput.Width = 315;
                    listBoxNewInput.Height = 150;
                    listBoxNewInput.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(listBoxNewInput_DoubleClick);

                    flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(labelInput);
                    flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(list
```

BoxNewInput);

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a wizard like app would be suitable for you. AFAIK there's no native wizard control in C# but you could implement one using tabs or using one of many in the web.